# Data Scraping Government Site

Tags: data, scraping, web-scraping

As I know it may be okay or may not be okay to data scrape a government website.  Would the following site be okay to data scrape?

https://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_carrquery.prc_carrlist

I would be using this data for my work.  I could gather the data manually but the time it would take would be extensive.

Comment: The best practice is see there is something in the site saying if it is ok to scrape, and check it out the robots.txt of this site.

Comment: Maybe make a Freedom of Information request for the data in a reasonable format (expecting you to click "next" 100 times to get 1000 records is not reasonable).